# Rails model attribute (a DateTime) has different value depending on how its called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am using Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.2.0.  I have a model called Ride that has a DateTime attribute called start_time.  When I call `Ride.find(1803)`, The start_time is shown as January 9th.  But when I call `Ride.find(1803).start_time`, It returns a start_time on January 9th.  How is this possible and how do I fix it?  Here's the full code I ran in the console:

```
irb(main):028:0> Ride.find(1803)
=> #<Ride id: 1803, start_time: "2016-01-09 00:00:00", end_time: nil, created_at: "2016-01-05 16:55:44", updated_at: "2016-01-05 20:35:38", user_id: 29, ride_type: nil, horse_id: nil, notes: "", available_to_ride_additional_horses: nil, admin_approved: false, weekday: nil, unavailable_to_ride: false, time_range_dropdown: "Morning", rider_name: "Matti Fisher", rider_last_name: "Fisher", rider_first_name: "Matti", edited_at: nil, requested_time: "2016-01-09 19:30:00">
irb(main):029:0> Ride.find(1803).start_time
=> Fri, 08 Jan 2016 19:00:00 EST -05:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because a date/time value is stored in the database as UTC and the default implementation of `inspect` for an ActiveRecord model doesn't apply any timezone conversion.

However, when you access the date/time value, Rails will apply the current timezone settings.

You can do the math. Since your timezone is UTC-5, both datetime represent the same object

```
2016-01-09 00:00:00 UTC
Fri, 08 Jan 2016 19:00:00 EST -05:00
```

As a proof, you can call

```
Ride.find(1803).start_time.utc
```

and you will get the date/time as UTC, that will probably be the same value you see when you print out the full record representation.